# Breaking slash, not non-breaking

Tags: html

[image: img]

Is there such a thing as a breaking slash?
Something that will allow for more lines?

Currently the slash is non-breaking..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a [`&shy;`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) and/or a [zero-width space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) for this purpose.

Comment: zero-width space was the answer !

Comment: Be careful when using a zero-width space because if you copy the text, it still contains the zero-width space character, so it won't work correctly for URLs.

Comment: Now that HTML5 has `<wbr>` (as in Aziz Shaikh's answer), I think that this answer actually ought to be deprecated (well, deprecated if you're supporting HTML5), for the reason given by MarthyM (and more broadly, because it involves inserting a character that doesn't really belong to the text).

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
<div>Citrate/<wbr>Lactate</div>
```

`<wbr>` is for word breaks telling the browser that it may insert a line break here if needed.

Comment: <wbr> now part of HTML5 I read. So I will use it right away. Thanks!